Rails 5.1.7 cache methods are not working
I'm trying to execute this statement of Rails Cache in console:
Rails.cache.fetch('some_other_key', expires_in: 24.hours) { 50 + 50 }

It is throwing error like this:
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2))

The rails version is Rails 5.1.7 and config.cache_store = :memory_store.
I tried to switch to redis store but error continue to be same.
This is the Full trace:
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/cache.rb:542:in `normalize_key'
meta_request (0.8.2) lib/meta_request/event.rb:61:in `sanitize_hash'
meta_request (0.8.2) lib/meta_request/event.rb:42:in `json_encodable'
meta_request (0.8.2) lib/meta_request/event.rb:18:in `initialize'
meta_request (0.8.2) lib/meta_request/app_notifications.rb:31:in `new'
meta_request (0.8.2) lib/meta_request/app_notifications.rb:31:in `block in <class:AppNotifications>'
meta_request (0.8.2) lib/meta_request/app_notifications.rb:82:in `block in subscribe'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:127:in `finish'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:46:in `block in finish'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:46:in `each'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb:46:in `finish'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:42:in `finish_with_state'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:27:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/cache.rb:555:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/cache.rb:287:in `fetch'
app/controllers/config_service/organization_flags_controller.rb:61:in `get_legacy_flags'
app/controllers/config_service/organization_flags_controller.rb:10:in `index'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:131:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:252:in `process_action'
searchkick (3.1.3) lib/searchkick/logging.rb:209:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.1.7) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:124:in `process'
actionview (5.1.7) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:189:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:253:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:31:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:844:in `call'
omniauth (2.0.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:202:in `call!'
omniauth (2.0.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:169:in `call'
omniauth (2.0.4) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:45:in `call'
bullet (7.1.6) lib/bullet/rack.rb:14:in `call'
meta_request (0.8.2) lib/meta_request/middlewares/app_request_handler.rb:15:in `call'
meta_request (0.8.2) lib/meta_request/middlewares/meta_request_handler.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.0.9.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.9.4) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.9.4) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.9.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:259:in `context'
rack (2.0.9.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:253:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
better_errors (2.10.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:87:in `protected_app_call'
better_errors (2.10.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:82:in `better_errors_call'
better_errors (2.10.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:60:in `call'
bugsnag (6.27.1) lib/bugsnag/integrations/rack.rb:51:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
rack-contrib (2.5.0) lib/rack/contrib/response_headers.rb:23:in `call'
meta_request (0.8.2) lib/meta_request/middlewares/headers.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
request_store (1.7.0) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.9.4) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.9.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.9.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
rack-cors (2.0.2) lib/rack/cors.rb:102:in `call'
railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:706:in `handle_request'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:476:in `process_client'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'


I got the solution
In Local:
This is because of active_support library issue.
To fix this:

Open file : replace version_number to ur ruby version number $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-<version_number>@edcast_super_admin/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/cache.rb
Replace def normalize_key(key, options) to def normalize_key(key,
options = nil)
This I verified with the higher version and took
the reference of it.


meta_request version 0.8.2 released 4/13/2024, rails 5.1.7 released 3/27/2019. <- this is your actual issue. Why not just upgrade to rails 5.2.X (honestly higher than that but this will get you past the immediate hurdle) rather than monkey patching an issue caused by compatibility between the meta_request gem and your current version.
